# CSS Quirk That Only Occurs In Chrome

Tags: css, asp.net, html, google-chrome

I'm writing an asp.net webpage for my class. It's my first, and I'm having to dive head-first into CSS, HTML5, and ASP.NET. I think I'm doing alright, but I'm having a weird CSS file issue with Chrome. I have a table that I want to center in the page, so I used

```
table
{
    margin: 0 auto;          
}​
```

in the file.

It works for IE, Edge, and Firefox, but Chrome refuses to center the table unless my table tag is

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto;">
```

I've tried searching Google and this site specifically to find out why Chrome is doing this when everything else I've tested it with works fine, but no result really answers this question. I can work around it for now, but would really like to know what I'm missing that's making my table sit against the left side of the browser window.

P.S. All of the other items in my CSS file are being accessed properly.

Comment: Have you used the Elements tab in the developer tools to see what styles are actually being applied at runtime?

Comment: In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u17mhvay/), both approaches work fine, so there must be something else at play in your situation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I checked the elements tab in Chrome dev tools. Today, it works just fine today. Apparently, it just needed a reboot. Weirdly enough, I have a second web form that had a border that worked yesterday without the CSS file link in the html for it, and today, I actually had to enter the link that was missing. Thanks for the suggestions, everyone!